# UITextField changing font size via Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I've been trying to adjust the font size for a UITextField that's embedded in a contentView of a UITableViewCell. I'm using cmd+T to bring up the font menu, and in there am using just the default font Helvetica size 18. Everytime I change the size it doesn't seem to make a difference at all when my UITextField is displayed. It's almost as if I need to do it programmatically for any changes to take place.

Any advice?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you uncheck the "Adjust to fit" option on the UITextField. Otherwise if your text is longer than the field the framework will automatically shrink the text to make it fit.